# a problem of xymatrix in overleaf

Tags: xy-pic, xymatrix

I have a problem with this code. In overleaf, I compile it but I do not see anything on the pdf document.

```latex
$$\xymatrixcolsep{32pt}\xymatrix{
P_{c_1}\oplus \cdots \oplus P_{c_s} \ar[r]^-{\left(P[\bar{\gamma}_{ij}]\right)_{r\times s}} \ar[d]^{f_2} & P_{b_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus P_{b_r} \ar[rr]^-{(P[\bar{\alpha}_1],\cdots, P[\bar{\alpha}_r])} \ar[d]^{f_1} && P_a \ar[r]^{d_a} \ar[d]^{f_a} & S_a \ar[r] \ar@{=}[d] & 0\\
K^{-2}_a\ar[r]^{\partial_a^{-2}} & K^{-1}_a \ar[rr]^{\partial_a^{-1}} && K^0_a\ar[r]^{\partial_a^{\hspace{.4pt}0}} & S_a \ar[r]  & 0,}$$
```

Can someone give me some ideas? thanks

Comment: If I add a standard preamble, I get the expected output

Comment: Can you send me your preamble please? in overleaf?

Comment: Nothing else than `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` after the diagram.

Comment: Overleaf? or your latex?

Comment: Yes thank you very much

Comment: Is there any easy way to change the code but not the output? because it does not work in my latex

Comment: I mean with tikzcd. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From by last comment of the user, here there is a version with `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep = huge]
P_{c_1}\oplus \cdots \oplus P_{c_s} \arrow[d, "f_2"] \arrow[r, "{\scriptstyle (P[\bar{\gamma}_{ij}])_{r\times s})}"] & P_{b_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus P_{b_r}  \arrow[r, "{(P[\bar{\alpha}_1],\cdots, P[\bar{\alpha}_r])}"] \arrow[d, "f_1"] & P_{a} \arrow[r, "d_a"] \arrow[d, "f_a"] & S_a \arrow[r] \arrow[d, equal] & 0 \\
K^{-2}_a \arrow[r, "\partial_a^{-2}"] & K^{-1}_a  \arrow[r, "\partial_a^{-1}"] & K^0_a \arrow[r, "\partial_a^{0}"] & S_{a} \arrow[r] & 0
\end{tikzcd}\]


\end{document}
```

[image]